# Calling methods of a Java subclass using Jython

Tags: java, python, jython

I have this Java class,

```
public class sample {
        public Integer foo1(Integer x){
            return x+5;
        }
    }
class SubClass extends sample{

    public Integer foo2(Integer x){
        return x+100;
    }
}
```

And with Jython I want to call `foo2` of the class `SubClass`. I ended up with the following Python code,

```
import SubClass, sample
java_file = SubClass()
print java_file.foo2(3)
```

But running the Python code returns this error,

```
AttributeError: 'SubClass' object has no attribute 'foo2'
```

I also want to print the super class of a class and it's signature including the attributes like public, abstract, etc.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first create a instance... the invoke the method... like the following example:

```
Beach.java

public class Beach {

    private String name;
    private String city;


    public Beach(String name, String city){
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

}
Using Beach.java in Jython

>>> import Beach
>>> beach = Beach("Cocoa Beach","Cocoa Beach")
>>> beach.getName()
u'Cocoa Beach'
>>> print beach.getName()
Cocoa Beach
```

You can read more [here](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html#using-java-within-jython-applications)

Comment: Thanks, but what if there is a subclass which I want to access its methods? As asked above, importing the subclass didn't work.

Comment: my answer is regarding to the fact that you didn't properly invoke the method... you can try to import them both and then invoke the method...

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work :(. I am unable to instantiate the `subclass`!

Comment: Nvm, it works now :), since the class is not public I had to change Jython's registry file by setting python.security.respectJavaAccessibility to false.

Comment: Good to know :) or another solution would be just to make the subclass public